# How does these special characters work in Perl?

Tags: perl, bash, terminal

```
print "\e[4m", $prompt, "\e[24m", "\e[1m";
```

It seems it doesn't work in bash:

```
[root@dev-test ~]$ echo "\e[4mhello world\e[24m\e[1m"
\e[4mhello world\e[24m\e[1m
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"\e" means ESC which is used for [VT100 escape sequences](http://ascii-table.com/ansi-escape-sequences-vt-100.php) and similar. Perl understands the ["\e" escape sequence](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) in strings and interprets it as a the ESC character (it can also be written as "\33" or "\x1b").

To use ESC with [echo](http://ss64.com/bash/echo.html), supply the `-e` option which enables these escapes to be processed:

```
echo -e "\e[4mhello world\e[24m\e[1m"
```

The transformation from the two characters "\e" to the single ESC character (with the value 0x1B) is done by `echo` itself (with `-e`) -- the shell does not handle the escapes which appear in quotes. The link for `echo` above also includes an example of such usage.

Happy coding.

Comment: So all terminals are VT100 terminals??

Comment: @new_perl: Pretty much all of them emulate VT100, with or without extensions to that. See `man terminfo` for more information.